# How to use the CLI of drawio-desktop?

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to automate the export of [drawio-desktop](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop) as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496531/178966) for Linux but under Windows. How would I do that as Windows doesn't have an exec command AFAIK?

Linux version: `exec /usr/local/bin/draw.io --crop -x -o {}.pdf {} \`

Comment: Can someone add [draw.io]? - I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
C:\Program Files\draw.io\draw.io.exe C:\path\to\files\ --crop -x -o {}.pdf {} .
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used in [leonheess](https://superuser.com/users/557506/leonheess)'s self-answer is only valid when used within the `-exec` action of the Unix `find` utility; it is invalid syntax for Windows command lines as-is.

The standalone equivalent for Command Prompt is:

```sh
"C:\Program Files\draw.io\draw.io" -x -o . --crop -f pdf C:\path\to\files\
```

PowerShell is the same, but add `&`  to the beginning. (see [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4#call-operator-))

`-x` will have drawio export files using the options that follow. `-o .` specifies the current directory for the output, with file names based on the input files. `-f pdf` specifies pdf as the output format, and output files will automatically get the `.pdf` extension.

`C:\path\to\files\` will have drawio attempt to convert every file in that directory, regardless of its format or file extension. Error messages will print for each failed conversion, but drawio will continue, processing all files it discovers. These errors can be avoided by giving individual files instead:

```sh
"C:\Program Files\draw.io\draw.io" -x -o . --crop -f pdf C:\src\foo.drawio C:\src\bar.drawio
```

which will create `foo.pdf` and `bar.pdf` in the current directory.

See

```sh
"C:\Program Files\draw.io\draw.io" --help
```

for the official CLI help.

---

*Tested on drawio version 23.0.2*